# Strings and integer values in tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this list here:

```
[('CITS1001,95', 'CITS1401,100', 'CITS1402,97', 'CITS2002,99', 'CITS2211,94', 'CITS2401,95', 'CITS3001,93', 'CITS3002,93', 'CITS3003,91', 'CITS3200,87', 'CITS3401,98', 'CITS3402,93', 'CITS3403,88')]
```

How do you make it so it looks like this?

```
[('CITS1001,95'), ('CITS1401,100'), ('CITS1402,97'), ('CITS2002,99'), ('CITS2211,94'), ('CITS2401,95'), ('CITS3001,93'), ('CITS3002,93'), ('CITS3003,91'), ('CITS3200,87'), ('CITS3401,98'), ('CITS3402,93'), ('CITS3403,88')]
```

I think you have to loop it but I can't get it to bracket like above.

In general how do you tuple correctly for the above output. The problem I am having is the string values and the integer values I believe.

I keep getting

[('C'), ('I'), ('T') ETC.. because they are string.

So for just an example. Say I have list `[John, 20, Jeff 30]`

How do I output it to `[('John', 20),('Jeff', 30)]`

Any help would be nice, thanks. :)

Comment: Can u please share the code that u tried so far to solve this?

Comment: U have provided 2 sample examples but both are different one is a list that has only one tuple and in another one only list is input?   So input can be of which type????  Your both sample examples have different set of input and output??????

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 1):

A comma is necessary. Hope this can help you!

```
mylist=['test,1','test,2','test,3']
mylist_tuple = [ (item,) for item in mylist]
###  output : [('test,1',), ('test,2',), ('test,3',)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for your first problem,

```
list_elmnts = [('CITS1001,95', 'CITS1401,100', 'CITS1402,97', 'CITS2002,99', 'CITS2211,94', 'CITS2401,95', 'CITS3001,93', 'CITS3002,93', 'CITS3003,91', 'CITS3200,87', 'CITS3401,98', 'CITS3402,93', 'CITS3403,88')]
procesd_list = []
for list_elmt in list_elmnts:
    for tuple_elmnt in list_elmt:
        tuple_elmnt_array = tuple_elmnt.split(',')
        procesd_list.append((tuple_elmnt_array[0], tuple_elmnt_array[1]))
```

As far as i know, you cant keep single element tuple as requested in you question

Answer (score 0):

Try this: And importing ast won't recognize this syntax thou using literal.

```
import re
sl="""[('CITS1001,95', 'CITS1401,100', 'CITS1402,97', 'CITS2002,99',
        'CITS2211,94', 'CITS2401,95', 'CITS3001,93', 'CITS3002,93', 
        'CITS3003,91',
        'CITS3200,87', 'CITS3401,98', 'CITS3402,93', 'CITS3403,88')]"""

sl=re.sub('\(', '', sl)
sl=re.sub('\)', '', sl)
sl=str(sl)

# Then import ast to convert it back to a literal
import ast
sl = ast.literal_eval(sl)

for nm in sl:
    #print('\n')
    print(nm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is expresses to examples that are not the same, and your list format of example 2 is mixture of two formats that I'm assuming should have been `['John,20', 'Jeff,30']` based off the format of example 1

**Example 1 Soution:**

```
l = [(j,) for i in l for j in i]
```

> ```
> [('CITS1001,95',), ('CITS1401,100',), ('CITS1402,97',), ('CITS2002,99',), ('CITS2211,94',), ('CITS2401,95',), ('CITS3001,93',), ('CITS3002,93',), ('CITS3003,91',), ('CITS3200,87',), ('CITS3401,98',), ('CITS3402,93',), ('CITS3403,88',)]
> ```

*Note: Expected output for example one is not what I think you meant, I believe this is more optimal*

```
l = [(j.split(',')[0], int(j.split(',')[1])) for i in l for j in i]
```

> ```
> [('CITS1001', 95), ('CITS1401', 100), ('CITS1402', 97), ('CITS2002', 99), ('CITS2211', 94), ('CITS2401', 95), ('CITS3001', 93), ('CITS3002', 93), ('CITS3003', 91), ('CITS3200', 87), ('CITS3401', 98), ('CITS3402', 93), ('CITS3403', 88)]
> ```

**Example 2 Solution:**

```
l = [(i.split(',')[0], int(i.split(',')[1])) for i in l]
```

> ```
> [('John', 20), ('Jeff', 30)]
> ```

**Expanded loop model:**

```
new_l = []
for i in l:
    new_l.append((i.split(',')[0], int(i.split(',')[1])))
```